# How to set defaultHtmlEscape to true without XML in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I want to avoid using XML configurations and therefore I made my `AppConfig` class where I have plenty of beans for different purposes.

I can't find how to prevent a XSS by setting `defaultHtmlEscape` inside my `AppConfig`. Everything I found was a config per form or globally in XML config.

My `AppConfig` now:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="org.maguss.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "org.maguss.*" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    //////////////////////////
     @Bean
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          em.setDataSource(dataSource());
          em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.maguss.model" });

          JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
          em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

          return em;
       }


       @Bean
       public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
          JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

          return transactionManager;
       }

       @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }

       Properties additionalProperties() {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        //  properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
          return properties;
       }
    //////////////////////////

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I ran into the same question, and found two ways to achieve this.

### 1. Add an entry to the `application.properties` file

You can add the following entry to the `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.context-parameters.defaultHtmlEscape=true
```

### 2. Create a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` bean

Alternatively, you can create a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` bean to apply the customisation:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

@Component
public class WebServerCustomisations 
    implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<AbstractServletWebServerFactory>
{
    @Override
    public void customize(AbstractServletWebServerFactory factory)
    {
         Map<String, String> initParams = factory.getInitParameters();             
         initParams.put(WebUtils.HTML_ESCAPE_CONTEXT_PARAM, Boolean.toString(true));
    }
}
```

Note that this method will only be applied for those web servers that have a factory deriving from `AbstractServletWebServerFactory`. At the moment, it looks like this is Tomcat, Jetty and Undertow.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should have a `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` instead of traditional `web.xml`, based on that you can:

```
public class YourServletInititializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    // root config, web config and servlet mapping

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true")

        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: May I combine that with my AppConfig class or is that another configuration class? Won't it cause any issues?

Comment: Are you using a `web.xml`?

Comment: No, but I have tried to put the config there and it doesn't work. I have also added it into each form and it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: I have same problem as stated here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/65447-htmlescape

Comment: Do you have a `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`?

Comment: No I don't have that.

Comment: How did you tell spring to pick `AppConfig` up as configuration?

Comment: May i ask what annotations? add them to your question